# Go - System Time in pico-second

Tags: go

Is it possible in go to get system time in less than nano second means in pico-second or like that? Actually, I want to measure two consecutive events time gap which I can't catch in nano-second in our fast system.

Comment: Are you detecting FTL neutrinos or what? Light travels only 0,3 millimeters in a picosecond ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The cost of calling profiling functions/instructions on modern hardware is larger (and mor espread and prone to deviance) than the interval you're going to measure. So even if you try, you'll get erroneous results.

Consider tracking time lapse for 100 events, if that's at all possible.

Comment: If nanosecond resolution isn't enough, I'd rather try 1000000 than 100 events to get a meaningful result.

Answer (score 3):

The time resolution is hardware and operating system dependent. The Go [time.Nanoseconds](http://golang.org/pkg/time/#Nanoseconds) function provides up to nanosecond time resolution. On a PC, it's usually 1000 nanoseconds (1 microsecond) or 100 nanoseconds at best.